# Symfony 3.4 NotFoundHttpException No route found for "GET /lucky/number"

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I'v created a symfony 3.4 project,and I've create  a controller following the doc (I had to change the controller namespace)

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
//namespace AppBundle\Controller; this is the default namespace in the doc

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class LuckyController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number")
     */
    public function numberAction()
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

But when I try to access to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/lucky/number` I get this error:

```
NotFoundHttpException  No route found for "GET /lucky/number"
```

I tried to clean the cache but didn't work and think I dont have to download any anootations library, I don't know what is wrong

Comment: So why don't you think you need an annotation package? https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html#annotation-routes

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Cerad the 3.4 doc page does not say to install the package, wasn't it included by default for a while?

Comment: @ArleighHix The folks that are trying to get the lucky number controller working tend to be new developers.  Very difficult to tell how they started their project especially when they are still using an ancient unsupported version.  There are a number of identical question with a number of very strange solutions.  In one case, the developer forgot the opening <?php tag.  Go figure.    Annotations of course are required.  Maybe they already have it installed.  Maybe they don't.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the namespace you also need to make some changes to your config.
You can tag the individual controller with `controller.service_arguments`:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    # ...

    # explicitly configure the service
    App\Controller\LuckyController:
        tags: [controller.service_arguments]
```

Or if you have changed the entire `AppBundle` namespace to `App` and you are using the [Symfony Standard Edition (version 3.4) services.yml](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/3.4/app/config/services.yml) configuration, just change all instances of `AppBundle` to `App`:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    # makes classes in src/App available to be used as services
    App\:
        resource: '../../src/App/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/App/{Entity,Repository}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
    # and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/App/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Of course always clear the cache after making any changes.

Comment: The error message indicates the route does not exist.  Generating routes is independent of controller services.  They may or may not need to use your posted code eventually but they need to get the route defined first.